# List with checkboxes in Reactive Form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

So I am trying to write as little handling code as possible when dealing with forms, however this use case has proven to be a roadblock for me (mostly mentally).

So I have a list of objects, which I want to assign to a form control within a reactive form. Initially, none of the available options should be selected. When selected the form control value should be populated either with a simple value (like `id: number`) or the object itself.

Here is the **component.ts**:

```
public pageForm: FormGroup;
constructor( private fb: FormBuilder ){}

public ngOnInit(): void {
   this.pageForm = this.fb.group({
     id: [null],
     requestedBy: [ null, Validators.required ],
     requestNote: [ '' ],
     absenceType: [ EnumAbsenceType.vacation, Validators.required ],
     shifts: [ [], Validators.required ]
   });
}
```

It is all about the last `shifts` FormControl.

The **template.html** for other controls looks trivial, ie:

```
<div><input type="text" formControlName="requestNote"></div>
```

But I also have this array of objects I need to display with checkboxes, so that when a checkbox is checked, the value is passed to shifts FormControl. The value passed should not be `true` or `false`, but either the id or the object itself. I would also like to avoid some kind of `(change)="onChange($event)"` type of code (which is the case now) so that the framework takes care of inserting into / deleting from the shifts array.

Any ideas?

UPD: Just for the sake of visualization, here is what it should look like when rendered:

```
     date           name
-------------------------------------
[ ]  23.05.2018     Max Mustermann
[ ]  24.05.2018     Neymar Jr 
[x]  25.05.2018     Roger Federer
[x]  26.05.2018     Rafael Nadal
[ ]  27.05.2018     Will Smith
```

So the `shifts` form control value should have two entries for Roger Federer and Rafael Nadal